# Getting Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'filename' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

When running a script containing this code:

```
print('Hello world')
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

I have double checked that I am in the current working folder (`os.getcwd()`).

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is the full code you are running? Also, where and how are you running this?

Comment: Yes this is the only code I am running. I use Atom text editor. Also created it in notepad.
Then I type the filename in command prompt.

I have had it working. The only thing I can remember that I have changed in my setup is that I installed beautifulsoup.

Comment: Now discovered that it workds when I restart command prompt, and type:
python filename

But it used to work before when I started python, by first typing in python in CP and then typing in the file name.

Comment: if the name of your file is `filename` you should write something like `python filename.py`. If you just write `python` first it will open the python interpreter. If you then write `filename` it's as if you are typing a Python command which has no meaning and raises this error

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
But I have been able to; first type in python in CP, go to current workding directory, and simply type in the filename.py.
But for some reason now that gives me the error. Also I find this way much nicer than having to type in python filename.py every time in CP.

Comment: If you open the python interpreter inside the command line, it is meant to run Python commands, not files. If you want to run a python file, you simply run it. Outside of the interpreter...

Comment: But I have been able to run files, i.e "filename.py" inside the python interpreter. But suddenly can't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use Command Prompt to run python file.

Go to your current directory that contains python file and open Command Prompt.
Run your python file as "python filename.py".

That will be good.

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer being able to start python in CP, go to the current working directory and being able to run files from there.